# Name for this measure on a positive Square Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given a positive matrix
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
a_{11} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & \cdots & a_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad a_{ij}>0
$$

Define $r_i$ as the sum of the entries in row $i$

$\qquad r_1 = a_{11} + \cdots + a_{1n}$

$\qquad r_2 = a_{21} + \cdots + a_{2n}$

$\qquad \qquad \qquad \vdots$

$\qquad r_n = a_{n1} + \cdots + a_{nn}$

Then define $R$ to be the product of $r_1$ to $r_n$

$\qquad R = r_{1} \times \cdots \times r_{n}$

Then finally, define a measure on the matrix to be the determinant of $M$ divided by $R$

$\qquad Measure(M) = \frac{Det(M)}{R}$

- Is there a name for this measure?

I know that it's geometric interpretation is the volume of the n-parallelopiped divided by the volume of the bounding n-cuboid. Just curious if it has a name so that I can read up other stuff about it. Thanks in advance!